# Cypress failed to make a connection to the Edge/Firefox in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing, browser, cypress

I created some VueJS test and run with Cypress.

Everything is OK until I run it on Jenkins (with a GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling)

Only `cypress run --browser chrome` and `cypress run --browser electron` work.

With Edge and Firefox, it returned this kind of error

```
Still waiting to connect to Edge, retrying in 1 second (attempt 62/62)
Cypress failed to make a connection to the Chrome DevTools Protocol after retrying for 50 seconds.

This usually indicates there was a problem opening the Edge browser.

The CDP port requested was 63444.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:63444
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)

Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm run cypress:run
    at makeError (C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Homepage\node_modules\start-server-and-test\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Homepage\node_modules\start-server-and-test\node_modules\execa\index.js:118:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm run cypress:run',
  command: 'npm run cypress:run',
  escapedCommand: '"npm run cypress:run"',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
```

How can I run it normally in Jenkins? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firefox has problems atm. Same for me. Couldn't get it to run locally.

Comment: Does your build agent have firefox and edge installed?

Comment: @agoff I think it doesn't. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: An update, after I upgraded cypress to 10.10.0, the `Still waiting to connect to edge` is still remains, but I've got new error, which is `All promises were rejected`.